# Let A,B be nxn matrix If $(A^2)(B^2) = (B^2)(A^2)$ , is $AB=BA$?

Tags: matrix-analysis

Let $A,B$ be $n\times n$ matrix

If $(A^2)(B^2) = (B^2)(A^2)$ , 
is $AB=BA$?

Answer (score 1):

It is not true in general that $A^2B^2=B^2A^2$ implies $AB=BA$. For example let
$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \quad \text{and} \quad B = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Can I know what motivated you to find the counterexample?

Comment: @taritgoswami: These matrices are both canonical examples of nonzero matrices whose squares are zero matrices, which means the condition $A^2B^2=B^2A^2$ is satisfied trivially. Matrices like this are great for counterexamples.

Answer (score 0):

No, just take the matrix (hope no miscalculations)

$ A = \bigg(\begin{array}{ll} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{array}\bigg) $
and 
$ B = \bigg(\begin{array}{ll} 0 & 0 \\1 & 0 \end{array}\bigg) $

Comment: Someone has already answered in same way. Can you explain it more clearly to make it an *different* answer ?